# Calculate a discrete mean in python

Tags: python, sum, range

I have a set of data points for which I have made a program that will look into the data set, from that set take every n points, and sum it, and put it in a new list. And with that I can make a simple bar plots.

Now I'd like to calculate a discrete mean for my new list.

The formula I'm using is this: `t_av=(1/nsmp) Sum[N_i*t_i,{i,n_l,n_u}]`
Basically I have nsmp bins that have `N_i` number in them, `t_i` is a time of a bin, and `n_l` is the first bin, and `n_u` is the last bin.

So if my list is this: `[373, 156, 73, 27, 16]`,
I have 5 bins, and I have: `t_av=1/5 (373*1+156*2+73*3+27*4+16*5)=218.4`

Now I have run into a problem. I tried with this:

```
for i in range(0,len(L)):
    sr_vr = L[i]*i

tsr=sr_vr/nsmp
```

Where nsmp is the number of bins I can set, and I have `L` calculated. Since range will go from 0,1,2,3,4 I won't get the correct answer, because my first bin is calculated by 0. If I say `range(1,len(L)+1)` I'll get `IndexError: list index out of range`, since that will mess up the `L[i]*i` part since he will still multiply second (1) element of the list with 1, and then he'll be one entry short for the last part.

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `L[i]*(i+1)` (assuming you stick with zero-based indexing).

However you can also use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to loop over indices and values together, and you can even provide `1` as the second argument so that the indexing starts at `1` instead of `0`.

Here is how I would write this:

```
tsr = sum(x * i for i, x in enumerate(L, 1)) / len(L)
```

Note that if you are on Python 2.x and `L` contains entirely integers this will perform integer division.  To get a float just convert one of the arguments to a float (for example `float(len(L))`).  You can also use `from __future__ import division`.

Comment: Your second version works, while the L[i]*(i+1) gives wrong answer. I wouldn't thought of that second way, which works perfectly. I'll accept it in 8 minutes :D Btw I still dk why that simple loop doesn't work properly :\
EDIT: I have that `from __future__` part :)

Comment: You are reassigning a new value to `sr_vr` on each iteration, when you want to be keeping a running total instead.  So you would put `sr_vr = 0` before the loop and then inside the loop you would use `sr_vr += L[i]*(i+1)`.